# Multiple TextViews update very slowly

Tags: android, textview, android-service

I have a Service that sends an Intent to my Activity every 0.1 seconds. I use it to update a custom implementation of a Chronometer. Here everything goes right. The problem comes when I want to update 14 TextView I have in a TableView inside a Fragment in my Activity. Here the app is very slow.

The method in my Activity where it receives the Intent from the Service:

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        long milis = intent.getLongExtra("milis",0);
        if( mFragment != null)
        mFragment.Update(milis);
    }
};
```

The code inside the Fragment where I update the TextViews:

```
public void actualizarTiempoJuego(long milis){
    // Se recuperan los tiempos acumulados y se aumenta la cantidad pasada como parámetro
    for(int i=0;i<7;++i) {
        long mCurrentMilis1 = mVectorMilis1.get(i);
        long mCurrentMilis2 = mVectorMilis2.get(i);
        TextView1 t1 = mListaTitularLayoutLocal.get(i);
        TextView1 t2 = mListaTitularLayoutVisitante.get(i);
        t1.setText(String.value(milis + mCurrentMilis1));
        t2.setText(String.value(milis + mCurrentMilis2));
    }
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong, or is it just that I'm trying to do something very complex in terms of efficiency?

Comment: I would create one String from `milis` and use it 14 times, rather than trying to create 14 identical Strings. And then use the Android tools to test whether a standard for loop, a for-each loop, or using Iterators provides the fastest results.

Comment: @Sam. This is an light version. I copied here like that for make it easier to understand. I edit it for make it more complet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Sherif brings up a good point about hidden alpha values that bog down your application a lot.
Depending on your platform you may also want to check

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true"... />
```

Another thing you can look into that may help performance is not firing off all those Intents.  Once you start firing intents you are getting the system involved and depending on how they are getting resolved it may take some extra time.

For this issue I like to use [Handlers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). They are more light weight than intent.
You may also want to look at [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). This is basically like a thread, but also gives hooks that run on the UI Thread so you can perform both perform a background operation and update the UI without have to post runnables.

EDIT: Lastly, you can always run your layouts through the [layoutopt](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/layoutopt.html) tool. I was personally told by Romain Guy himself that if your drawing too slow, than you need to draw less. Just check out a screenshot (from a less than ideal view tree, but well within the max) from the profiling tool. You can see how much of the resources view drawing takes up. It's very important to keep this as lean as possible if you want your app to be responsive.
[image: Profiling View Drawing Resource Consumption]

EDIT: It is no longer called layoutopt, it's called [lint](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/). Check your ~/android-sdk/tools/

Comment: HardwareAccelerated didn't help to improve the performance. I'm looking for the Link tool. I'll told you later.

Comment: Yeah. I said hardware acceleration may help, depending on your platform. You also need to limit drawing and the use of intents. What link tool did you told me later?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say lint tool.

Answer (score 5):

I have once faced a situation where a fragment was really slow.

I am just predicting that your fragment has some kind of alpha and it is drawn on a 'heavy' activity.

The conclusion is that each time you are setting the text of a textview your whole view hierarchy is being invalidated.

It seems that fragments have this flaw. Anyway, use some layout instead of the fragment and check if it remains 'slow'.

---

ADDITION: A wrap_content textview will cause much more delay after a `setText` than a fill_parent textview.

Comment: Duuuuuude, you have saved my life bro, thank you!!! Changing textView's width to `matchConstraint` did the trick. UI became smooth and responsive.

Answer (score 3):

You're likely running into slowdowns due to layout management with TableLayout and TextView.  Every time you update text in one of those, a large amount of view measuring has to take place in order to put the characters in the right place on the screen.  You should really just profile the app yourself using Traceview to find out.  More information at: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

I've had the exact same issue you're seeing with the same type of layout (Fragment > TableLayout > Multiple TextViews).  One way to test if your TableLayout/TextView setup is to blame is simply replace all that with a single TextView.  That will probably run pretty well.  Then put your 14 views into a FrameLayout or RelativeLayout.  Even if they all overlap, you should still get decent performance, because it's the complexity of the TableLayout view measurements that's really causing slowdown.

Comment: I did what you told me. I begin with a single TextView and everithing was right. But when I added 5 more TextViews, It became slow again.

Comment: Did you remove the TableLayout before this test?  I am 99% positive the lag you're seeing is from the View measuring needed to properly align several rows of a table layout combined with the measuring of TextViews with dynamic text.

Comment: Yes. I removed TableLayout as you suggested. I change the fragment which included the TableLayout for the textviews.

Comment: What layout did the TextViews sit in after you removed the TableLayout?  Are you saying that a total of 6 TextViews in a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout was still causing slowdown?

Answer (score 0):

As someone said you can use HardwareAccelerated but this is not a great solution, you will waste ram and cpu if you can't solve it in a different way. A solution probably more safety is to reduce the number of TextView. Try to reduce 14 to 7 and it will go twice faster. Usually is hard to do it but if you put the objects in a strategy position a pair of TextView one above other can be together if you make a TextView with two lines. And don't forget that findViewById is so expensive, if you will use a view object often find it one time and hold its reference.

Answer (score 0):

Benchmarks are always useful for determining where slowness actually comes from, but I feel pretty confident suggesting that sending an Intent is probably much slower than updating 14 TextViews.  Sending 10 Intents per second is a sign that you're Doing It Wrong (TM).  This is just isn't what they're for.

> Am I doing anything wrong, or is it just that I'm trying to do something very complex in terms of efficiency?

Updating 14 TextViews per second isn't inherently complex; you should be able to easily achieve this with a more appropriate application design. [ASyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) come to mind as possible tools, but it's hard to know what's best without knowing more about exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: I've used an Hanlder to update the TextViews but I'm still having the same behaviour.

Comment: @gutiory Did you get rid of the Service and the Intents? Adding a Handler on top of that isn't going to make things any faster. I'm suggesting using a different architecture with a Handler or AsyncTask *instead* of a Service and Intents.

Answer (score 0):

- You can try to declare vars outside the loop :

  ```
  public void actualizarTiempoJuego(long milis){
      // Se recuperan los tiempos acumulados y se 
      // aumenta la cantidad pasada como parámetro

      long mCurrentMilis1;
      long mCurrentMilis2;
      TextView1 t1;
      TextView1 t2;

      for(int i=0;i<7;++i) {
          mCurrentMilis1 = mVectorMilis1.get(i);
          mCurrentMilis2 = mVectorMilis2.get(i);
          t1 = mListaTitularLayoutLocal.get(i);
          t2 = mListaTitularLayoutVisitante.get(i);
          t1.setText(String.value(milis + mCurrentMilis1));
          t2.setText(String.value(milis + mCurrentMilis2));
      }
  }
  ```
- And to `setText()` with mixed type, you can try `setText("" + milis + mCurrentMilis2);`

Comment: maybe "onReceive" blocks somewhere, and using an asynctask for the UI update could speed up process, too